# Bug in my 'next offset' algorithm - C++

Tags: c++, file, sorting, archive, offset

I am trying to apply filenames to the files loaded from an archive.

For the first step, I create an array of structs that hold three bits of information. The filename, the file size and the offset in the file (from the beginning). The file sizes and offsets are initially read in to the structs. Then, I decode the filenames and read them into a vector.

Here is where it gets tricky. The filenames in order apply to the order of the offsets. The offsets however are not in order. For example:

```
File 1:
Name:
Size: 20102
Offset: 16

File 2:
Name:
Size: 23419
Offset: 2040

File 3:
Name:
Size: 145
Offset: 350
```

So with 3 filenames decoded into my vector, I would apply filename #1 to file 1, filename #2 to file 3 (because it has a lower offset), and finally filename #3 to file 2.

Now, my algorithm for doing this doesn't seem to work correctly. Here is the code:

```
// Keep track of the last offset we used
    int last_offset = 0;
    int current_offset = 0;
    int index = 0;

    // Finally, apply the correct filenames to the correct files
    for(int i = 0; i < file_names.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < file_count - 1; j++)
        {
            if(j == 0)
            {
                current_offset = files[j].offset;
            }

            if(files[j].offset > last_offset && files[j].offset < current_offset)
            {
                index = j;
                current_offset = files[j].offset;
            }
        }
        files[index].name = file_names[i];
        last_offset = current_offset;
    }
```

file_names is my vector with the strings in it. file_count is subtracted by 1 because it includes the directory file for the archive which does not need to be counted. It is also the highest offset and therefore not even dealt with.

Basically, this code tries to find the next highest offset every time and then apply the next file name in the vector.

Here is the output from my error log:

```
<-!-> File debug name: 
<-!-> File size: 17464
<-!-> File offset: 47974
<-!-> File debug name: 1dirt.bmp
<-!-> File size: 17462
<-!-> File offset: 12
<-!-> File debug name: rrock.bmp
<-!-> File size: 17464
<-!-> File offset: 17011
<-!-> File debug name: mtfloor.bmp
<-!-> File size: 5176
<-!-> File offset: 30725
<-!-> File debug name: 
<-!-> File size: 17640
<-!-> File offset: 134953
<-!-> File debug name: 
<-!-> File size: 158
<-!-> File offset: 140286
<-!-> File debug name: 
<-!-> File size: 134188
<-!-> File offset: 81658
<-!-> File debug name: lights.wld
<-!-> File size: 17464
<-!-> File offset: 34273
<-!-> File debug name: 
<-!-> File size: 1496
<-!-> File offset: 139799
<-!-> File debug name: 
<-!-> File size: 17464
<-!-> File offset: 61625
```

This indicates it has clearly not worked.

The other option I can do is **sort the array of structs by offsets ascending,** which I have no clue how to do but would make this process much easier as I could just apply the names in order.

Thank you for your time and let me know if you see the error.

Comment: Have you noticed that in your example and your error log that your offsets and sizes are overlapping?

Comment: @BenJackson What exactly do you mean by overlapping?

Comment: Look at `1dirt.bmp` in your example.  It's at offset 12 with size 17462.  The first offset that would be fully beyond that file is at offset 17462+12 = 17474, but the file `rrock.bmp` is at offset 17011 which overlaps.

Comment: @BenJackson Wow. Nice find. The files are compressed in the archive so the file size is the decompressed total size meaning they don't actually overlap at all. Thank you for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting, sorting, sorting! Otherwise you'll get an O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm. Not good. But you don't have to sort the `files`, instead construct a sorted index to the `files` array as follows:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct CompareOffset {
    bool operator ()(const file_type* x, const file_type* y) const {
        return x->offset < y->offset;
    }
};

vector<file_type*> vec;
for(size_t i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
    vec.push_back(&files[i]);
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), CompareOffset());

for(size_t i = 0; i < file_names.size(); i++)
    vec[i]->name = file_names[i];
```

Here `file_type` is your `struct` describing a file.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Was about to create a second array which had the index in order but this is much more efficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you'd be better off sorting your offsets first, but the specific bug in your algorithm is how you initialize `current_offset`.  Just outside the `for (j ...` loop you need to set it to "infinity", or some offset value so high that it will not prevent the first `j` that passes the `last_offset` test from becoming current.

Comment: Good catch. I spent about 20 minutes on your website. Damn. ben.com I bet you get offers all the time for it. Awesome stuff about lego raytracing.